# Want to align linearlayout inside another, but setGravity() doesn`t work

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to align a linear layout inside another linear layout programmatically, but `setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)` doesn`t work.

I know the differences between `gravity` and `layout_gravity`.

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/initial_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/conversationwrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_yellow"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messagecontent_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Message_content"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timestamp_tv"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="HH:MM"
            android:ems="2"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code of getView() in my Adapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_conversation, parent, false);
    }
    wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.conversationwrapper);
    initial_wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.initial_wrapper);
    time = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_tv);

    Message coment = getItem(position);

    content = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.messagecontent_tv);


    content.setText(coment.content);
    time.setText(getCurrentTimeStamp());

    wrapper.setBackgroundResource(!coment.mine  ? R.drawable.bubble_yellow :     R.drawable.bubble_green);
    initial_wrapper.setGravity(!coment.mine  ? Gravity.LEFT :  Gravity.RIGHT);


    return row;
}
```

But it always happen to be on the left, even when the image is green.

The strange thing is that if I type

```
android:gravity="right"
```

inside initial_wrapper, It works in the preview but not in the device.

I'm using a Moto G and a Nexus 5, but neither of them work

Comment: Not related, you are missing orientation tag in the Linear Layouts.

Comment: @Skynet when there is no orientation is treated as Horizontal

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be here : `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`, how you supose to set `android:gravity="right"` here, if your layout is filling whole parent? You should try to use

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/initial_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
```

instead of :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/initial_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
```

Comment: "gravity" always applies to the content(makes sense when you layout is maximized wrt dimensions either a matchparent or a fixed size) within whereas layout_gravity applies to the layout(you need to wrap_content or fixed size for this to make sense). OP is correct in the manner of assigning gravity

Comment: @humblerookie but in this code this content __suppose to fill whole parent__, so i think he needs to try this

Comment: @nikmyers I tried this at first, but I also read the differences between layout_gravity and gravity and it's the gravity the thing I want

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/initial_wrapper"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity = "left"
>
```

in your `getView()` do this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = initial_wrapper.getLayoutParams();//will need to casting  
lp.gravity=   Gravity.RIGHT; // this is the important part
initial_wrapper.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

hope it helps

Comment: I tried it but It didn't work. Changed the initial_wrapper width to wrap_content and it doesn't even show correctly in the editor :/ But thank you!

Comment: sorry sorry sorry sorry Sir, i made a little mistake check my edit.@JavierLunaMolina

Comment: it crashes: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: hmm... im very lousy.. i have rolledback my edit.you say this one does not work? please sir remove this line in your getView `initial_wrapper.setGravity(!coment.mine  ? Gravity.LEFT :  Gravity.RIGHT);` and try this current code i have given, with wrap content as the width of the initial wrapper @JavierLunaMolina

Comment: Now it doesn't crash but it doesn't work... It is driving me real crazy

Comment: okay Sir, @JavierLunaMolina i want to give you an extended help, so i will create a simple listview program achieving your desires and send  it to at this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77204/extended-help)